# Regression with non-cointegrated I(1) series

Tags: panel-data, stata, fixed-effects-model, cointegration

I have 4 variables for a panel of N metropolitan areas over T years:

- productivity
- number of patent applications
- population
- share of graduates in the labor force

I wanted to regress `log(productivity)` over `log(patents)`, `log(population)` and share of graduates, along with time & metropolitan area fixed effects.

Of course, since all these variables are I(1) I thought about doing an ECM. However, when applying cointegration tests for panel data on these 4 variables (`xtwest` in Stata), the null of no-cointegration could not be rejected.

What should be the proper procedure in that case ?

Thank you

Comment: Model the first differences of the variables.

Comment: Could it be the case that there is a cointegration relationship between your variables but in different transformations (e.g. productivity instead of log(productivity))?

Answer (score 1):

If you find that there is no cointegration, your model is likely to be misspecified. This is probably because you are omitting very important variables, which are correlated with other regressors, and that **are essential in the long run cointegration relationship**. Remember that what cointegration looks for is the set of variables that jointly define a long-run, **stable** relationship.

My suggestion is to look for more variables, until you can find a cointegration relationship. The main reference for doing this is, nothing else than the theory. If it happens that you cannot find a cointegration relationship, that is also interesting (publication bias anyone?). You might look to argue why that is the case.

Then, you could follow Richard's suggestion and run the model in differences, but the information you can get is, in my experience, **very limited**, and you still can have misspecification problems that tests cannot highlight. That is the beauty behind a structural model and the battery of associated tests allowed by, for example, error correction models.

Finally, if you need to defend your results against serious people (not because of them but because you want a reliable theory), in my experience models in differences are insufficient, specially in **modern macroeconomics**, where everything is centered about cointegration.

Comment: Arguments like *models in differences are insufficient, specially in modern macroeconomics, where everything is centered about cointegration* have little to do with statistical logic. If your goal is to impress colleagues or peers, do whatever you like; but if you want reliable results, better pick a model that is statistically sound. Regarding *run the model in differences, but the information you can get is very limited*: this is too general to be true. Regarding *you still can have misspecification problems that tests cannot highlight*: this is always true and thus not very useful.

Comment: But ECM are theoretically and statistially sound models! Models in differences are not. They are quite apart from the general equilibrium economic theory. Impressing colleagues is not an end in itself but a test on how sound your methods are. Not rejecting a cointegration test is way more powerful that any serial correlation test you will ever not reject in a model in differences. Yes, of course, any model has limitations, as they are all statistical artifacts dealing with noisy data. But that does not mean everything is equally unreliable.

Comment: Sorry, you are plain wrong saying *Models in differences are not [statiscally sound]*. So far your claims are supported neither by statistical arguments nor by references. Also, what is the economic argument for why population should be cointegrated with productivity or share of graduates in the labour force?

Comment: Your right, I have not provided arguments. I'm just asserting that based on my knowledge of the modern macroeconomic literature, where barely no one uses them (they seem to be more popular in financial economics, where series are highly non-stationary, and cointegration relationships are probably unexistent due to the volatile nature of the market...using differences is the only choice then). Instead, researchers use cointegration models, constructed from theory, structurally full (in terms of assumptions, number of lags, etc).

Comment: Regarding the second question, it's responsibility of the OP to find out. I have not claimed anything about it. But, regardless of whether in this particular case there is a coint. rel, they are a positive construct which the science aims to look for. Finally, I encourage you to write an answer that can provide to be satisfactory for the OP. I will most definitively looking forward to it (I've suscribed to the topic).

Comment: My answer is taken straight from standard econometrics textbooks: if there is no cointegration, use first differences. I did not post one since I believe there must be older post addressing it, I just do not have the energy to dig them up. Also, while you have not claimed anything about the particular relationship, you have encouraged the use of (V)ECM, which is inappropriate in absence of cointegration. Therefore, you would be contradicting yourself if there actually was no reason for the variables to be cointegrated. In any case, I appreciate the discussion with you. Thumbs up.

Comment: Thumbs up x2! Notice that the core of my answer is "look for more variables". I should emphasize that.

Comment: Purely technically, adding more variables will not induce cointegration within the existing variables, and so the relationship between the original variables would still be modelled in first differences. Any new error correction terms would necessarily involve new variables but never only the old variables. So you may expand your system but the subsystem will not become cointegrated, and long-term relationships between the old variables would still be absent(!). (I do not say you necessarily claim this, though.)